# How does the compiler differentiate indentically-named items

Tags: c, assembly, scope, compiler-construction

In the following example:

```
int main(void) {
    int a=7;
    {
        int a=8;
    }
}
```

The generated assembly would be something like this (from Compiler Explorer) without optimizations:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $7, -4(%rbp)   // outer scope: int a=7
        movl    $8, -8(%rbp)   // inner scope: int a=8 
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

How does the compiler know where the variable is if there are duplicately-named variables? That is, when in the inner scope, the memory address is at `%rbp-8` and when in the outer scope the address is at `%rbp-4`.

Comment: "*How does the compiler know*" Because the language requires it. How does the compiler *implement* it is a different question, and there is no universally valid answer to that, since that's a choice each implementation can make in its own way.

Comment: @dxiv sure, I suppose a better phrasing might be what would be an example implementation, at least conceptually, to keep track of duplicated names.

Comment: An example implementation would be a hash table that uses linked-lists to resolve collisions.

Comment: Or the compiler creates some sort of tag for every scope, and keeps a table of variables whose keys are pairs `(identifier, scope-tag)`.

Comment: Entering a new scope, a compiler could add new symbols in a stack, finding collisions on the same level when creating, and finding collisions on all levels, when referencing.

Comment: That is why gcc provides the `-Wshadow` compiler option -- to make sure you catch any shadowed variables and either avoid them, or confirm that they do not result in unspecified program values. (most compilers provide a similar option)

Comment: You are asking how I know that my friend named Alex is different from my brother named Alex. The answer is I have more information about each than just their name.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to implement the local scoping rule. Here is a simple example:

- the compiler can keep a list of nested scopes, each with its own list of symbol definitions.
- this list initially has a single element for the global scope,
- when it parses a function definition, it adds a new scope element in front of the scope list for the function argument names, and adds each argument name with the corresponding information in the identifier list of this scope element.
- for each new block, it adds a new scope element in front of the scope list. `for (` introduces a new scope too for definitions in its first clause.
- upon leaving the scope (at the end of the block), it pops the scope element from the scope list.
- when it parses a declaration or a definition, if the corresponding symbol is already in the current scope's list, it is a local redefinition, which is forbidden (except for `extern` forward declarations). Otherwise the symbol is added to the scope list.
- when it encounters a symbol in an expression, it looks it up in the current scope's list of symbols, and each successive scope in the scope list until it finds it. If the symbol cannot be found, it is undefined, which is an error according to the latest C Standard. Otherwise the symbol information is used for further parsing and code generation.

The above steps are performed for type and object names, a separate list of symbols is maintained for `struct`, `union` and `enum` tags.

Preprocessing is performed before all of this occurs, in a separate phase of program translation.

Answer (score 3):

The C programming language has some specification, like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (or newer ones). That specification defines in §6.2.1 the ***scope* of an identifier**.

So any C compiler should follow that specification.

How does a C compiler implements that specification requires a good book for explanations. I recommend the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

Some simple or complex C compilers are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source). Look inside the source code of [TinyCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), or [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) to understand how they implement that specification (they have [symbol tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table), but details are specific to each compiler).

> How does the compiler know where the variable is if there are duplicately-named variables?

It manages symbol tables, and update them when parsing blocks. Usually, a compiler build some [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the compiled source code, and leafs in that tree representing variables refer to some symbol table. The GCC compiler documents its [Generic Tree](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html) and [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) data structures and provide [dump options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) to output them. You could also compile your `foo.c` as `gcc -S -O -fverbose-asm foo.c` and look into the emitted assembler code `foo.s`.

---

At last, **your example can be considered as *poor* programming style**. Some coding guidelines (like [MISRA-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) or [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html)) disallow or discourage it. Your [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) process should catch such code (in my opinion, your example is a quite unreadable code).

#### My feeling is that single letter variables should have a very small scope - a dozen of lines at most.

I suggest to **look** (for inspiration) **inside the C code of *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) projects** (like [GNU bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). Care has been taken to choose understandable names.

Take advantage of modern source code editors like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/). You can configure them to type long identifiers with a few keyboard presses (they have [auto-completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete); and some input libraries like [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) provides that too). Since you (or your colleagues) will spend much more time in *reading* source code than in *typing* it, such an effort (naming well your variables and identifiers) is worth your valuable time.

If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as your compiler, invoke it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get a lot of warnings and debug information. You could also use static source code analysis tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

**For real life software projects** (for example [GTK](https://gtk.org/)), **you'll have a document specifying coding conventions**, and you could write some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) checking most of them. See also the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project.

For some parts of your software project, you may use C code generators like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). In some cases, you would have your own C code generator. Then be sure to generate *long* C identifiers to reduce the possibility of name clashes.

Some [code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) tools are renaming most C identifiers. If you ship C source code without comments and with most identifiers generated like `_0TwK4TkhEG` the resulting C code can be compiled at your client site and would practically stay unreadable. You technically could write a code obfuscator transforming readable C code to cryptic C code.

Comment: The code in the question is fine as a [mcve] of a local shadowing another local.  It's obviously not intended as anything more than that because it doesn't do anything else.  I don't think you need to spend half your answer on the fact that such shadowing is normally a bad idea and poor style; worth mentioning as a PS that it is, and that compilers warn about it, but no reason to assume the OP doesn't already know this.

Comment: In fact, when questioning how compilers work, "bad code" can make good thought experiments.